# dump() not working in Drupal 8 (blank page, debbugging is enabled)

Tags: theming, 8, debugging

I want to use `dump()` in my `.twig` template (inside custom theme).

The problem is, when I place `{{ dump() }}` the page is just blank.

I have had:

1. Set `twig.confing debug: true` in `services.yml`.
2. Cleared cache.

The moment I remove `{{ dump() }}` everthing works.

After hours of googling I've found some information about mystery `$settings['twig_debug'] = TRUE;` [here](https://drupalize.me/blog/201405/lets-debug-twig-drupal-8) (I don't even have such line in my file, but adding it doesn't change a thing) and `$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(...` (where to find it even?).

I work on clean & fresh Drupal 8 installation, turing debbuing on (step 1.) does include comments in source code (as it should) but use `dump()` once and all you see is just an blank page.

Comment: Have you checked the drupal log?

Comment: There is probably a PHP error associated with the blank screen. As far as I know, you want to go with Kint rather than dump() now. See https://www.drupaleasy.com/quicktips/drupal-8-debugging-kareful-klicking-kint

Comment: Blank screen means mostly memory error, and since dump() prints out all variables it could be a hint

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I agree with the comment left for the question: It seems you have an *out of memory* issue. Check the error log for the server.

I had the same problem with `dump()` and `kint()` in an implementation of `template_preprocess_views_view_field()`, while trying to output the content of a row, on a clean and fresh Drupal 8 installation. 
I found a workaround for `kint()`, which seems to temporary fix the memory issue. Add the following settings in the config.default.php file for the Kint module.

```
/** @var int max array/object levels to go deep, if zero no limits are applied */
$_kintSettings['maxLevels'] = 4;
```

Take it as a hint: Print a specific variable, not the whole array of variables.

Comment: It is also possible to only print the variable keys (though I forgot how).

Comment: Thank you. Out of memory was the problem. Is there any `maxLevels` settings for `dump()` (something like `$_kintSettings` you provided for `kint()`)?

Comment: @Eyal I guess you were thinking about `dump(_context|keys)`

Comment: Wasn't that. But if it works then it is fine as well.

Comment: `dump()` uses `$output = Variable::export($input)` to output the variables array. It seems that there is no way to set how many level to go deep into array.