# How to add the twig debug extension

Tags: theming, 8, debugging

in `/var/aegir/platforms/drupal8-dev/sites/my_site_uri/settings.php`

```
  # Additional site configuration settings.
  if (is_readable('/var/aegir/platforms/drupal8-dev/sites/my_site_uri/local.settings.php')) {
    include_once('/var/aegir/platforms/drupal8-dev/sites/my_site_uri/local.settings.php');
  }
```

in `/var/aegir/platforms/drupal8-dev/sites/my_site_uri/local.settings.php`

```
       <?php # local settings.php

$settings['container_yamls'][] =DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/default/services.yml';
```

in `/var/aegir/platforms/drupal8-dev/sites/default/services.yml`

```
 parameters: 
   twig.config:
     debug: true
     auto_reload: null
     cache: false
```

The firebug console comments are working meaning twig debug is activated but dump (twig debug extension ) is not working .  **why?
is there anything more to set in services.yml ?**

```
  {{ dump() }}
```

Comment: The config mentioned above actually enables the dump twig function, but you might get a white screen of death for large objects. You can try `{{ dump('juast a string') }}` and see if it outputs somethig. More details below.

Answer (score 3):

Turn on Twig debugging by:

Copy sites/example.settings.local.php and rename to sites/default/settings.local.php

Go to sites/default/settings.php and uncomment the code below the comment relating to "Local development override configuration" and save the file.

```
if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/settings.local.php')) {
  include __DIR__ . '/settings.local.php';
}
```

Open sites/development.services.yml in a text editor and add the following to the bottom of the file and then save the file

```
  parameters:
    twig.config:
      debug: true
      auto_reload: true
      cache: false
```

Note: use two spaces for each indent. Twig can be fussy with this.

The debugging will be visible as html comments in the source code. Use Chrome or other developer tools to inspect.

If you want to inspect the data structure of variables in a speciifc template, install Devel module and enable Devel and Devel Kint and then add this in your template:

```
# to dump everything
{{ kint() }}


# to dump a variable
{{ kint(page) }}


# to dump lower down in the data structure
{{ kint(page.content) }}
```

Comment: twig debugging is working as i say in my msg. but the dump function is not working  twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions. As for kint i have activated devel kint module and putting {{ kint() }} gives me a WSOD with nothing in the logs !?

Comment: Apologies for my detailed answer. I meant for you to check your settings against my answer. I found this post where someone was having and out of memory issue (and suggested solution) because dump or kint was too large. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/204598/dump-not-working-in-drupal-8-blank-page-debbugging-is-enabled

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$settings['container_yamls'][] = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/my_site_uri/services.yml';
```

or to keep it more generic:

```
$settings['container_yamls'][] = __DIR__ . '/services.yml';
```

Comment: twig debug is working in firebug but the dump function is not working http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html

Answer (score 1):

> As for kint i have activated devel kint module and putting {{ kint() }} gives me a WSOD with nothing in the logs !??

I had the same problem as [mentioned here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2764023#comment-11395337), the solution is:

> According to Devel maintainer **willzyx**:
>
> *you can edit `modules/devel/kint/kint/config.default.php` and set
>   `$_kintSettings['maxLevels']` to a lower number (the default is 7)*

So try lowering it to 5 or 4.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comment above - the [dump](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/dump.html) twig function is available, if in the twig.config:debug is set to true (as mentioned already in the original question)

If enabled, you can try `{{ dump('just a string') }}` in your template, and it should output the correct value.

However, according to [this article](https://drupalize.me/blog/201405/lets-debug-twig-drupal-8) it is pretty likely, that you'll end up with a whitescreen of death due to a out of memory exception if you try to debug a complex class like node or _context. To get around this, you can try something like:

`{{ dump(_context|keys) }}`

This will at least give some insight of what can be accessed.